# Accidentally changed the owner of /bin and other directories

Tags: linux, permissions, system-restore, chown

I recently made something very, very stupid. Instead of typing: `chown adam ./*` I wrote: `chown adam /*` (I forgot about the very important dot). Now I have some files with owner `adam` instead of... hmm I don't really know who. I can't even call `su` and login as root because I get: `su: cannot set groups: Operation not permitted`. I am able only to run my Arch Linux cd, run it in EFI mode, login as root and call `arch-chroot /mnt`, where under `/mnt` my main Linux partition is mounted. The situation is bad but not terrible. Is there any way to restore my system?

Comment: I would start with `sudo chown -R root /bin /sbin /lib /usr /sys /boot /etc /dev` from inside the chroot - This *should* get you a bootable system, but I'm not 100% sure. Might want to wait for someone to confirm that this won't make the situation worse.

Comment: Read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/wrongly-set-chmod-777-problems

Comment: Thank you very much. Darth Android tip worked for me. @Daniel: Thanks, I will get familiar with that.

Comment: Just curious, why not `chown ... *`? Skip the `/` completely?

Comment: @DanielBeck +1, this will help prevent a recurrence of this issue.

Comment: @DanielBeck: I was typing very quickly, not it doesn't make sense also to me ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start with `sudo chown -R root /bin /sbin /lib /usr /sys /boot /etc /dev` from inside the chroot - This should get you a bootable system, but I'm not 100% sure. Might want to wait for someone to confirm that this won't make the situation worse.

Note, if you simply chown'd the files, you're in a much better position than someone who chmod'd or chgrp'd their system. Most files on a single-user system (i.e., used just by you) are either owned by you (in /home/username) or owned by root. There might be a few weird files in `/var` and there are definately some in `/run` and `/tmp` which are owned by the services that created them. Try `sudo chown root /var /run /tmp` (note the lack of `-R`) for those directories.

You will probably then want to wipe out the `/run` and `/tmp` contents (`sudo rm -rf /run/* /tmp/*` - Be very careful that this is typed correctly), since they are transient and rebuilt by applications when the system is restarted, and this is much easier than trying to track down the owners and fix that.

`/var` is going to be a complicated mess. Many daemons expect to be able to write there (mysql, apache, etc.), and have folders nested inside. It's safe to reowner the the top-level contents (`sudo chown root /var/*`), but the stuff in the folders needs to be restored carefully. You might look in the live-cd's `/var` folders for some hints.